# How can i fix problem that terraform EC2 resource depends on eks module

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I want to provision EC2 instances (resource) after eks (module) is provisioned. Also, is it possible to establish dependencies between modules and resources in Terraform?

Here is .tf files

ec2.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "ubuntu_bastion" {
  
  
  ami = "ami-0c9c942bd7bf113a2"
  availability_zone = var.azs[0]
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "Groom"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.bastion_sg.id]
  subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("../Groom.pem")
    host = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./deploy.sh"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/deploy.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo sh deploy.sh"
    ]
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./lb_controller.sh"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/lb_controller.sh"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./lb_controller.yaml"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/lb_controller.yaml"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo sh lb_controller.sh"
    ]
  }

  tags = {
      Name = "ubuntu_bastion"
  }
  depends_on = [module.eks.eks_name]
}
```

eks.tf

```
locals {
  az_subnet_mapping = {
    "ap-northeast-2a" = "20.0.1.0/24"
    "ap-northeast-2c" = "20.0.2.0/24"
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.10.0"

  cluster_name    = var.eks_name # variables.tf 에 있는 변수선언
  cluster_version = "1.24"


  vpc_id                         = module.vpc.vpc_id # vpc.tf 에 있는 vpc id 끌어오기
  subnet_ids                     = module.vpc.private_subnets
  cluster_endpoint_public_access = true

  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    one = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t2.medium"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1
      subnets = [local.az_subnet_mapping["ap-northeast-2a"]]
    }

    two = {
      name = "node-group-2"

      instance_types = ["t2.medium"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1
      subnets = [local.az_subnet_mapping["ap-northeast-2c"]]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_ingress" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = module.eks.cluster_security_group_id
}
```

An attempt was made to provision using `depends_on = [module.eks.eks_name]`, but the EC2 instance (resource) was not dependent on the EKS (module) and the EC2 instance was provisioned first